# Can't make JTextField ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jtextfield

I'm trying to add an `ActionListener` to a `JTextField` and make that text field the action listener itself.  Whenever I do that I get an error, saying

```
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type JTextField is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField)
```

### Code

```
String strBox1;

JTextField textBox1, textBox2, textBox3;

JTextArea textArea1, displayArea;

public textBoxes()
{       

    setLayout (new GridLayout(10,2));

    JLabel query1 = new JLabel("Daily Savings:");
    add(query1);
    textBox1 = new JTextField("Dsave", 5);
    add(textBox1);
    textBox1.addActionListener(textBox1);
    //textBox1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());

    JLabel query2 = new JLabel("Current Age:");
    add(query2);
    textBox2 = new JTextField("Cage", 5);
    add(textBox2);

    JLabel query3 = new JLabel("Initial Savings amount:");
    add(query3);
    textBox3 = new JTextField("ISA", 5);
    add(textBox3);

    JLabel query4 = new JLabel("Age of Retirement:");
    add(query4);
    JTextField textBox4 = new JTextField("AoR", 5);
    add(textBox4);

    JLabel query5 = new JLabel("Annual Retirement Income:");
    add(query5);
    JTextField textBox5 = new JTextField("ARI", 5);
    add(textBox5);

    JLabel query6 = new JLabel("Life Expectancy:");
    add(query6);
    JTextField textBox6 = new JTextField("LR", 5);
    add(textBox6);

    JLabel query7 = new JLabel("Interest Rate on Return of Savings:");
    add(query7);
    JTextField textBox7 = new JTextField("IRoRoS", 5);
    add(textBox7);

    JLabel query8 = new JLabel("Inflation %:");
    add(query8);
    JTextField textBox8 = new JTextField("I%", 5);
    add(textBox8);
}


class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener 
{
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("change -" + e);
    }
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
}

class MyTextActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically, `JTextField` does not implement the `ActionListener` interface, so you can't do what you are trying.

You need to supply a valid `ActionListener` implementation.

See [How to write Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

The error's telling you exactly what's wrong with your code. It's on this line here:

```
textBox1.addActionListener(textBox1);
```

This method is expecting an instance of an ActionListener to be passed in. Perhaps you wanted to use MyTextActionListener?

```
textBox1.addActionListener(new MyTextActionListener());
```

Answer (score 2):

You put wrong parameter at `addActionListener(..)`. Change from

```
 textBox1.addActionListener(textBox1);
```

To,

```
 textBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
       // Do the action event here.
   }
 });
```

Read the tutorial of [How to Write ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). Also, check out the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).

Comment: +1 for being the first with a basic solution and a link to the tutorial. @OP don't forget to take a look at the Table of Contents in the tutorial for more information on Swing basics.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the code:

```
textBox1.addActionListener(this);
```

*or*

```
textBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
     ....
   }
}
);
```